# Memory warning after loading numerous pages, need to clear memory from webview

Tags: ios, webview, memory-limit

I have a gif I have embedded into a html style web page in the supporting files. Every view controller has a webview in it with this html page. The gif is a moving background which I want in all of my view controllers (45 total). I cant find a way to clear the memory after moving on to the next viewcontroller. After about 14 viewcontrollers back and forth, the app crashes. Here is what I have:

In the H:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

In the M:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    NSString *pathImg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"gif"];
    NSString* webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"<html><body><img style='width:760;height:1024;' src=\"file://%@\" /></body></html>", pathImg];

    [webView loadHTMLString:webViewContent baseURL:nil];

    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webView.opaque=FALSE;
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
@end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could be leaking `ViewController` objects.  In that case the memory increase is valid and showing you an actual code problem.  Otherwise call `[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];` when you are done with your view and the webview should release the image.

Comment: loadHTMLString:@"" didn't work for me... fixed it by loading the abount_blank page. [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];